# How to use a saved (.h5) keras model with CasADi for MPC?

Tags: tensorflow, dynamic-programming

I am new to CasADi. I have a saved Keras model in .h5 format that represents my system dynamics, and would like to use CasADi and develop a Model Predictive Control. Can you help on how to do this? is there any alternative useful library to use?
I could not find any useful resources online.